# Do CDMA based time servers passively read timing information from the cell network?

Tags: time, ntp

GPS based time servers are receive only, that is, they passively read the timing information from the GPS network.  Do CDMA based time servers work the same way?  In other words, do CDMA based time servers passively listen to CDMA signals without transmitting information to the cell network?  We have an application where bi-directional communication with a cell network is not practical, but believe we could operate in a receive only fashion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDMA time servers do not need to transmit and generally have no ability to do so. Mobile devices that use CDMA must synchronize their clocks before they are capable of transmitting as you need to find the timeslices you are supposed to transmit in.